# Broaden number of clades in pheatmap dendrogram

Tags: r, pheatmap

I am using the pheatmap package and would like to change my dendrogram to broaden the clades that cluster each of my columns.

Each column represents an individual. I would like individuals to be clustered more broadly. For example, my visual does not need to illustrate the difference between individual A and individual B (shown in the thick black box below).

I thought the kmeans_k argument would allow me to manipulate this, but I am receiving the following error: "Error: number of cluster centres must lie between 1 and nrow(x)". Is adjusting kmeans_k the correct approach, or is there another way? Thank you.

[image]